# MongoDB Dates in Date and String format for the same column

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection where the same column has Date and String format dates for different records, with the same ISO pattern like 2021-04-22T14:10:48.751779Z.

And I need to build a unified query for search, with such =, >, < options for search.
The second problem is an input search query has a different pattern ("2021-04-22")

So the question is:

- can I write some kind of transformation of existing table data before the search, for example from Date to String, or in case I have a string value this transformation would not cause any exception.
  In this case, I would be able to perform a search by $eq, $lt, $gt, and $regex query options.
  I`m not considering casting strings to dates even if this is possible because my input did not have "14:10:48.751779Z" this part of the date and query would not find anything because of dates would not match. For this case, $regex looks like the only solution.

Or your any other suggestions would be considered.

Current query which not satisfies case when DB column is String type:

```html
{
   "aggregate":"collection_name",
   "pipeline":[
      {
         "$match":{
            "$and":[
               {
                  "some_column":{
                     "$eq":"some_value"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "date_column_with_string_or_date_type":{
                     "$gt":{
                        "$date":"1980-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "$project":{
            "_id":1
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Please specify your desired output pattern.

Comment: @bimjhi there is no such pattern, I need to check if records with a specified date exist.

Comment: Are you looking for $toDate to convert string to date and searc? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/

Comment: Please post your initialization code. We just can't understand the part you got stuck in.

Comment: @DeepakSingh Cant use this. Some records have String format and in this case, there are no matching even if they same dates.

Comment: Irrespective of the field with different data types _and_ a query filter, you _can only compare data of the same type_. That means you need to convert your data to a type (one type only within the query) and perform your match.

Comment: @prasad_ Irrespective of the field type in Mongo can I covert it to String and after compare with string type from a query?

Comment: You can. Make sure the format is something like 'yyyy-mm-dd' (the string format need to be with year, month, day, hour, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using $expr and $toString
This works with Date And String types of "date_column"

```html
$match: {
    $expr: {
        $gt : [
        { $toString:"$date_column" },
        "2021-04-22"
        ]
    }
}
```

operator: